# How to tie annotations to spring properties?

Tags: spring-boot

In my Spring boot application I have around 30 controller  classes. Each class has a `@CrossOrigin` annotation. When I work on it in eclipse it’s fine, but when I deploy to production I need to remove them.

So I was thinking to create a custom property in `application.properties` and somehow tie it to CrossOrigin annotations. So I can set property `my-annotation=false` and this will cancel the CrossOrigin annotations everywhere in the application. I tried looking into reflection but couldn’t figure out how to do it.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Instead of using an annotation, you could configure CORS in your configuration class. There you should be able to access your app properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid, spring doesn't work this way - once you've put an annotation its there for all controllers.

Technically this annotation is used somewhere deep inside in spring MVC `(org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#initCorsConfiguration)` so its not advisable to fiddle with it.

Probably it's possible to override the beans of this type by custom implementation and putting them into some configuration that will take place in production only and will not be loaded by default. But again, this is too "internal" solution.

Instead I suggest creating a global cors configuration outside the controller, so no `@CrossOrigin` annotation will stay in controllers.

So the **first step** would be defining a `WebConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
class MyGlobalCorsConfiguration {
 @Bean
 public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
        }
    };
 }
}
```

The **second step** is to apply this configuration only upon some certain conditions:

It's possible to do with `@ConditionalOnProperties` annotation that can be put on the whole configuration or one single bean:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "myproject.cors.enabled", havingValue = "true", 
 matchIfMissing = false)
@Configuration
class MyGlobalCorsConfiguration {
 ....
}
```

Now during the **third step** you should put the property `myproject.cors.enabled=true` into the application properties that gets loaded only in production environment or something